# Web SQL DataBase - Execute asyc call and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm trying to make an asynchronous call (SELECT statement) that allows me to continue the main thread as shown in the following code (I need the execution sequence: "A", 2, "B"):

```
function test(tx) {

// Drop Table
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS city');

// Create Table
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city (id, name)");

// Insert 2 rows
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO city (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Roma')");
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO city (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Bari')");


alert("A");   

    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM city', [], function (tx, results) 
    {
       alert(results.rows.length);
    }, null);

alert('B');
}
```

But I get, "A", "B", 2

How I can achieve the execution sequence "A", 2, "B"?

Thanks.
Paul

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronous query to Web SQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903155/synchronous-query-to-web-sql-database)

Answer (score -1):

This is one major problem with websql API. It fixed in IndexedDB API, such that the spec defines all requests must placed on transaction must execute in order it placed against. WebSQL don't have that condition and hence it can execute in any order.

The workaround is to use request success callback. There is a thread here in stackoverflow that explain the concept with examples.